# View Neptune Graph Schema using Jupyter notebook

Tags: gremlin, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-neptune, gremlinpython, graph-notebook

Is there a way to view the schema of a graph in a Neptune cluster using Jupyter Notebook?

Like you would do a "select * from tablename limit 10" in an RDS using SQL, similarly is there a way to get a sense of the graph data through Jupyter Notebook?

Comment: Check out this blog post for an example: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/let-me-graph-that-for-you-part-1-air-routes/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how large your graph is as to how well this will perform but you can get a sense of the type of nodes and edges you have using something like the example below. From the tags you used I assume you are using Gremlin:

```
g.V().groupCount().by(label)
g.E().groupCount().by(label)
```

If you have a very large graph try putting something like `limit(100000)` before the `groupCount` step.

If you are using a programming language like Python (with gremlin python installed) then you will need to add a `next()` terminal step to the queries as in:

```
g.V().groupCount().by(label).next()
g.E().groupCount().by(label).next()
```

Having found the labels and distribution of the labels you could use one of them to explore some properties. Let's imagine there is a label called "person".

```
g.V().hasLabel('person').limit(10).valueMap().toList()
```

Remember with Gremlin property graphs vertices with the same label may not necessarily have all the same properties so it's good to look at more than one vertex to get a sense for that as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to visualize your graph ie. want to view all the child nodes below a given root node, then you can use this below gremlin query in a jupyter notebook cell.

```
    %%gremlin -p v,e  
    g.V({label},{property},{value}) 
    .repeat(outE().inV()).until(outE().count().is(0)).path() 
    .by(valueMap({propertiesList})).by(label)
```

Change

1. {label} : vertex label
2. {property} : vertex prop to filter
3. {value} : value of prop
4. {propertiesList} : list of properties of vertex to be shown in graph